# How to manage connections with Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, sidekiq

Each worker should have it's own resource connection. I read the docs, but it wasn't clear if each thread runs a separate instance of the worker.

If so, does this create a connection that is unique to each worker?

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform 
    connection.send 'message'
  end

  def connection
    @connection ||= Connection.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq basically does this when executing each job: `HardWorker.new.perform`.  So, yes.